# CSS Link to Div When Printing

Tags: javascript

I found some code to help my print part of a page within a

That code is:

```
function Clickheretoprint()
    { 
      var disp_setting="toolbar=yes,location=no,directories=yes,menubar=yes,"; 
          disp_setting+="scrollbars=yes,width=650, height=600, left=100, top=25"; 
      var content_vlue = document.getElementById("print_content").innerHTML; 

      var docprint=window.open("","",disp_setting); 
       docprint.document.open(); 
       docprint.document.write('<html><head><title>JEFCO AEROMODLERS AUCTION INVOICE</title>'); 
       docprint.document.write('</head><body onLoad="self.print()"><center>');          
       docprint.document.write(content_vlue);          
       docprint.document.write('</center></body></html>'); 
       docprint.document.close(); 
       docprint.focus(); 
    }


I have a CSS that I refer to as a link:

<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="Styles/Compact/Style_doctype.css" title="prefered">
```

The data displayed on screen utilizes the CSS in the link without a problem.

When I click to print my print window pops up containing the portion of the page within the

```
<DIV</DIV> however, the CSS style is gone!

<DIV> looks like this <div id="print_content">
```

How can I get the pop up window created by the function Clickheretoprint() to retain the CSS specified in the link?

Thanks//

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you add the stylesheet when you write to it?

```
win.document.write('<head><link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="yourStyleSheet.css"></head>');

win.print();
win.close();
```

Comment: This is the answer; popup windows don't magically inherit CSS :)